# Redirect to originally requested page after authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Java Spring v4. When a user tries to access restricted pages they are forced to authenticate. After a successful authentication I wish to redirect the user back to the page they were trying to access. I can accomplish this using the request "Referer" header but after reading more I found this method to be insecure cause it can be easily spoofed ( i.e. request.getHeader("Referer") )

I thought that perhaps I could set a Session attribute to record the referring page but the problem is after authentication a new session is created and I don't have access to the Session attribute. It seems that perhaps using SessionFixationProtectionStrategy will copy Session attributes after authentication. Does anyone have any simple examples of redirecting a user back to the original page they requested?

Comment: I think spring security has handled that already. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#form-login-flow-handling

Comment: Take a look at this example from baeldung. I believe it does what you want:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler now instead of using AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Comment: Is using SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler setUseReferer(true); really any better than using request.getHeader("Referer")  ?

Comment: Why do you think, that `referer` header is a problem? You can only redirect to pages you are allowed to see. There is no difference if you use the `referer` or calling the URL in the next step.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being overly cautious? Reading other posts "this is a client-controlled value which can easily be spoofed/omitted by the client."

Comment: Yes, but all URLs are client-controlled. So best security would be to allow no URLs at all? I can't see any security issue with `referer`.